# I'm having an invalid syntax error with the socket module

Tags: python, sockets

```
#!/bin/python

import socket
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 30002
list = []
passwd = "UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ"

for i in range(1000, 9999):
        list.append(i)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
iter = 0
data = s.recv(1024)
# Brute forcing loop
while 1:
        s.send(passwd + " " + list[iter]
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if "Fail!" not in data:
                print s.recv(1024)
                s.close()
        else:
                print "Not: " + list[iter]
                iter += 1
s.close()
```

I get an invalid syntax on the s.recv call, but I believe that the socket isn't initiating a valid handshake. I can connect to the daemon through netcat.

Answer (score 3):

You miss the parenthesis after the s.send() function

Comment: Oops, thanks. Not sure how I missed that.